# Can Someone check the Definite Integration Question and tell me if there is any mistake in it?

Tags: integration

[image]

Please check this question if it is right solution or not ?

Comment: Look at the first line you labeled (Ans.).  Then look at how you distributed the minus sign in the next line...  Otherwise, I believe you're alright.

Answer (score 0):

Your indefinite integral is okay. Something wrong in your substitution of the end point as your answer is not 2.9...

[Here is the verification](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%281/sqrt%28x%29%2b1/sqrt%28exp%28x%29%29,%20x%29):